# BigQuery - How to import WRITE_TRUNCATE for big query data overwrite?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, gcloud

I'm using the python BigQuery client (https://github.com/tylertreat/BigQuery-Python) to upload data from google cloud storage to a table. I want to overwrite the data so I need to set the writeDisposition to WRITE_TRUNCATE. Where should I import the WRITE_TRUNCATE from?

```
job = client.import_data_from_uris( gs_file_path,
                               'dataset_name',
                               'table_name', 
                               schema, 
                               source_format=JOB_SOURCE_FORMAT_CSV,
                               writeDisposition=WRITE_TRUNCATE,
                               field_delimiter='\t')
```

Here is the current error - `NameError: name 'WRITE_TRUNCATE' is not defined.`

Also, I would be interested to know importing of other similar name constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if before anything you run:

```
from bigquery.client import JOB_WRITE_TRUNCATE
```

and then run:

```
job = client.import_data_from_uris( gs_file_path,
                                   'dataset_name',
                                   'table_name', 
                                   schema, 
                                   source_format=JOB_SOURCE_FORMAT_CSV,
                                   writeDisposition=JOB_WRITE_TRUNCATE,
                                   field_d

elimiter='\t')
```

It might already work for you. Still, I think that defining yourself this variable and using it as you wish might work the same way and be a bit simpler, like so:

```
write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
job = client.import_data_from_uris( gs_file_path,
                               'dataset_name',
                               'table_name', 
                               schema, 
                               source_format=JOB_SOURCE_FORMAT_CSV,
                               writeDisposition=write_disposition,
                               field_delimiter='\t')
```

if you wanted some appending operation would you just change the value to `write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND'` and so on.

Comment: Thanks. The first suggestion worked for me. Strangely, the second suggestion errors with *TypeError: import_data_from_uris() got an unexpected keyword argument 'writeDisposition'*